# How to insert an element into a sorted vector using binary search

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

Hello I have an issue where I don't know if my implementation of inserting into a vector using binary search is right.
I have two vectors one stores class objects. The second one is the one that is suppose to be sorted. The second vector holds the indexes of the first vector, these indexes are suppose to be sorted lexicographically (small to largest). I'm trying to make my program run O(log(n)). Here it's what I have...

```
void Trendtracker:: add_hashtag(string ht)
{

    Entry tweet;
    tweet.count = 0;
    tweet.hashtag = ht;
    if (E.empty())
    {
        E.push_back(tweet);
        S.push_back(0);
    }


    int l, m, r;
    l = 0;
    r = S.size() -1;

    while (l < r)
    {
        m =(l+r)/2;
        if(E[S[m]].hashtag == ht)//found #1
            return;
        else if (E[S[m]].hashtag < ht)// searches right
            l = m +1;
        else
            r = m-1; // searches left

    }

    if( l ==r && E[S[l]].hashtag == tweet.hashtag)// found #2
        return;

    E.push_back(tweet);

    //if not found and lower than the lowest
    if(l==0 && ht < E[S[l]].hashtag)
    {
        //S[0]= E.size()-1;
        S.insert(S.begin(), E.size()-1);
    }

    // if not found but is higher than highest
    else if(l == S.size()-1 && E[S[l]].hashtag < ht)
    {
        S.push_back(E.size()-1);
    }

    // if new hashtag goes in the second index
    else if(l==0&& r==0 && E[S[r]].hashtag< ht)
    {

        S.insert(S.begin()+1, E.size()-1);
    }

    // if not found and l & r are somewhere in the middle
    else
    {

        S.insert(S.begin()+l, E.size()-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use something like `std::lower_bound()` instead of rolling your own: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound

Comment: If `if (E.empty())` condition is true then you can return after execution of that `if` block. No point executing rest of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the container to insert/remove in the middle frequently then the `std::vector` might not be your best bet.

Think about it: `std::vector` stores elements in contiguous memory, so every time you want to insert in the middle of it, you will move all the elements after it. It's faster to look up (even more if it's sorted) but the overhead on insertion is something to have in mind.

You could take a look at lists or other kind of containers which implement a linked list, since insertion is as simple as creating a node, changing `next` and `prev` pointers of the element before, the element itself and the element after.

Hope it helps

Comment: The suggestion of binary-search insertion into vectors is mentioned in this article, in addition to arguments as to why a vector should generally be preferred to lists. http://www.stroustrup.com/Software-for-infrastructure.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The crux of algorithm is this:

1)Using binary search check for the mid index value

```
  a) If the value to be inserted is less than mid value - check the (mid - 1) index if it is a valid index. If mid -1 is also less then you have to insert at current mid position.Otherwise, Change high to mid -1 and continue to search left
  b) If the value to be inserted is greater than mid value - check the (mid + 1) index if it is a valid index. If mid + 1 is also greater then you have to insert at mid + 1 position. Otherwise, change low to mid + 1 and continue to search right
  c) Handle overflow cases
```

Below is a sample code for vector based insertion using binary search:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void insert(vector<int> &arr,int value)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = (int)(arr.size() - 1);
    int mid = low+(high - low)/2;
    int indexToInsert = -1;
    while(low<=high)
    {
        if(mid < 0 || mid > arr.size()-1)
            break;
        if(value < arr[mid])
        {
            //check if previous index is valid and lesser than value
            if(mid-1 >= 0)
            {
                if(arr[mid-1]<value)
                {
                    indexToInsert = mid;
                    break;
                }
            }
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        else if(value > arr[mid])
        {
            //check if next index is valid and greater than value
            if(mid+1 < arr.size())
            {
                if(arr[mid+1]>value)
                {
                    indexToInsert = mid+1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        mid = low+(high - low)/2;
    }
    if(indexToInsert == -1)
    {
        if(mid<=0)
            indexToInsert = 0;
        else if (mid>=arr.size())
            indexToInsert = (int)(arr.size());
    }

    arr.insert(arr.begin() + indexToInsert, value);
}

void printVec(vector<int> vec)
{
    for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<vec[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    vector<int> vec;
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
        vec.push_back(i+(i*1));//used to create a ascending sorted array
        cout<<vec[i-1]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";

    insert(vec, 3);
    cout<<"After insertion of 3: \n";
    printVec(vec);

    insert(vec, 25);
    cout<<"After insertion of 25: \n";
    printVec(vec);

    insert(vec, 11);
    cout<<"After insertion of 11: \n";
    printVec(vec);

    insert(vec, 1);
    cout<<"After insertion of 1: \n";
    printVec(vec);
    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know if there are any bugs in this.